# How to create custom field in content object

Tags: custom-field, content

I tried to create fields in content object, But i couldn't get any solution. Even I gone through the [page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_fields.htm&type=0), but it does not provide much clarity.

Can anyone help me to create a custom field in content object.

Comment: Try this:- 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_fields.htm&type=0

Comment: Hi, @AaryaTiwary, I already gone through it. But while i checking in my account I am not finding any `object management settings for content`

Comment: That object management Setting is for Lightning Experience, you are using salesforce Classic or Experience??

Comment: I am using salesforce classic and i found the answer using your post. 
Thank you.

Comment: just i saw the full [document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_fields.htm&type=0). I found salesforce file over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Salesforce Classic

Step 1: In quick find box search for **salesforce file**

Step 2: click on **Field**, you will be directed to this page 
[image]

Create your Custom Field..!!

Comment: Can you please explain about this?

Comment: If you see the page layout of content object, few of fields are not visible even if we added them to page layout. where as few of fields are visible even if we are not added them to page layout. it gives some confusion. Can you clarify me in this?